# Java can't find java.util.function.Consumer

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I'm porting some code from C# to Java and since the code had an `Action`, I want to use a `Consumer` in Java, however, I appear to have some wrong configuration with my project's configuration:

[image]

My module is already using a language level with support for lambdas, so I would expect the function package to be found

[image]

Coming from C# world, I still get a bit lost with classpaths and project configuration, what else am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android can not do Java 8; the whole lot of `java.util.function` is Java 8, though.